# How to Install a .cer file and Export to a .pfx file with private key

Tags: c#, x509certificate2

I have a requirement from my Client to Install .cer file without a private key and export it to a .pfx file with Private key using C#

I tried all the different solutions provided which allowed me to export .cer to .pfx but without a key and .pfx file is empty

```
string file = @"C:\TestCert1.cer";
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
X509Certificate2 test = new X509Certificate2(X509Certificate2.CreateFromCertFile(file));
string name = test.SerialNumber;
store.Certificates.Insert(0, test);
store.Add(test);
store.Close();

byte[] certData = store.Certificates.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx, "MyPassword");
File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\MyCert.pfx", certData);
```

Comment: This does not make sense. For exporting the private key it have to be already installed in the certificate store (because a cer file has no private key hence it must be already there). And if it is already installed you don't need to install the cer file before exporting certificate+private key.

Comment: @Robert, Thank you for the response. I will rephrase my question. I have a .cer file and if I install it manually and try to export it from Personal store after installation, I get a popup with an option to export it with Private keys but when I try to implement the same using C# code, I am not able to. Please let me know if I need to provide any other additional information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part is OK:

```
string file = @"C:\TestCert1.cer";
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
```

Instead of

```
X509Certificate2 test = new X509Certificate2(X509Certificate2.CreateFromCertFile(file));
```

you want the much simpler

```
X509Certificate2 test = new X509Certificate2(file);
```

Not sure what this was for, you never used the variable.

```
string name = test.SerialNumber;
```

This line does nothing useful.  (`store.Certificates` returns a new collection that's a copy of the state of the store at that time... you add to that collection then let it fall out of scope).

```
store.Certificates.Insert(0, test);
```

This one actually adds the cert to the store, so it's OK, except not necessary for your goals.

```
store.Add(test);
```

So now you close the store then try to export it.  Which doesn't make sense, the closed store's `Certificates` property always returns an empty collection.  (It should have thrown, but that ship sailed long ago).

```
store.Close();

byte[] certData = store.Certificates.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx, "MyPassword");
File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\MyCert.pfx", certData);
```

What you probably want is to open the file, then look through the store and see if there's a match, and export the match.

```
using (X509Certificate2 filter = new X509Certificate2(file))
using (X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser))
{
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

    // The bytes making up the certificate, in DER/binary form.
    byte[] filterRawData = filter.RawData;

    foreach (X509Certificate2 storeCert in store.Certificates)
    {
        if (storeCert.RawData.SequenceEquals(filterRawData))
        {
            File.WriteAllBytes(outputFileName, storeCert.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx, password));
            return;
        }
    }   
}

Console.WriteLine("No match found...");
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. It helped me in exporting the certs to pfx and sorry for responding late.

Comment: @user11115500 if the answer has helped you, consider marking it as accepted (some sort of hollow check mark should be present, click it and it’ll fill).

Comment: I have done it but I am getting following message.Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: @user11115500 https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers (sounds like you voted instead of accept)

Comment: Accepted it now. Thanks for directing me